# function attached with a button not working after changing its id in ajax success callback

Tags: jquery, ajax

When I click the button its id, name and val attribute change successfully in ajax success. But if If I click it again the old function attached to the previous id is called not the one attached to the new id. I checked other posts but they did not worked for me either.

```
<input type="submit" name="textareaInsert" id="textareaInsert" class="textareaInsert" value="Insert data">


//script
$(document).ready(function() {
    graph_post_data();
    graph_update_data();
});

function graph_post_data() {
    $('#textareaInsert').on("click", function() {
        var poll_id = $('#poll_id').val();
        var graph_data = $('#graphPost').val();
        var ownerid = $('#ownerid').val();
        var ownername = $('#ownername').val();
        var insert = 'insert';

        if(ownerid != null || graph_data != '') {
            $.ajax({
                type:"post",
                url:"reg2.php",
                data: {insert:insert, poll_id:poll_id, graph_data:graph_data, ownerid:ownerid, ownername:ownername},
                success: function() {
                     $('#textareaInsert').attr("id", "textareaUpdate").attr("name","textareaUpdate").val("Update");
             }
            }).error(
                function() {
                    console.log("Error in inserting graph data")
                }
            ).success(
                function(data) {
                    var Poll_insert_data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    $('#poll_author').text(Poll_insert_data.data.publisherName);
                    $('#owner_input_data').append(Poll_insert_data.data.data);
                }
            );
        } else {
            alert('Please write something first.');
        }
    });
}


function graph_update_data() {
    $('#textareaUpdate').on("click", function() {

         var poll_id = $('#poll_id').val();
         var graph_data = $('#graphPost').val();
         var ownerid = $('#ownerid').val();
         var ownername = $('#ownername').val();
         var update = 'update';

         if(ownerid != null || graph_data != '') {
         $.ajax({
         type:"post",
         url:"reg2.php",
         data: {update:update, poll_id:poll_id, graph_data:graph_data, ownerid:ownerid, ownername:ownername},
         }).error(
         function() {
         console.log("Error in updating graph page data")
         }
         )
         .success(
         function(data) {

         var Poll_insert_data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
         $('#poll_author').text(Poll_insert_data.data.publisherName);
         $('#owner_input_data').text("").append(Poll_insert_data.data.data);

         }
         );
         } else {
         alert('Please write something first.');
         }
    });
}
```

When I click the button first time 'Insert data' successfully changes its attributes to that of "Upload". But when I click "Upload", function graph_post_data() is called instead of graph_update_data(). I'm not getting what's the problem. Please help me figure it out.

Comment: The `id` is supposed to be a unique identifier for that particular element. You are not supposed to change it at all even if there's a valid reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you attach your functions using event delegation, they will be applicable to the id rather than bound to the element:

```
$(document).on('click', '#textateaUpdate', function () {
    ...
}
```

EDIT: Your solution with the changes I suggested above:

```
<input type="submit" name="textareaInsert" id="textareaInsert" class="textareaInsert" value="Insert data">


//script
$(document).ready(function() {
    graph_post_data();
    graph_update_data();
});

function graph_post_data() {
    $(document).on('click', '#textareaInsert', function() {
        var poll_id = $('#poll_id').val();
        var graph_data = $('#graphPost').val();
        var ownerid = $('#ownerid').val();
        var ownername = $('#ownername').val();
        var insert = 'insert';

        if(ownerid != null || graph_data != '') {
            $.ajax({
                type:"post",
                url:"reg2.php",
                data: {insert:insert, poll_id:poll_id, graph_data:graph_data, ownerid:ownerid, ownername:ownername},
                success: function() {
                     $('#textareaInsert').attr("id", "textareaUpdate").attr("name","textareaUpdate").val("Update");
             }
            }).error(
                function() {
                    console.log("Error in inserting graph data")
                }
            ).success(
                function(data) {
                    var Poll_insert_data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    $('#poll_author').text(Poll_insert_data.data.publisherName);
                    $('#owner_input_data').append(Poll_insert_data.data.data);
                }
            );
        } else {
            alert('Please write something first.');
        }
    });
}


function graph_update_data() {
    $(document).on('click', '#textareaUpdate', function() {

         var poll_id = $('#poll_id').val();
         var graph_data = $('#graphPost').val();
         var ownerid = $('#ownerid').val();
         var ownername = $('#ownername').val();
         var update = 'update';

         if(ownerid != null || graph_data != '') {
         $.ajax({
         type:"post",
         url:"reg2.php",
         data: {update:update, poll_id:poll_id, graph_data:graph_data, ownerid:ownerid, ownername:ownername},
         }).error(
         function() {
         console.log("Error in updating graph page data")
         }
         )
         .success(
         function(data) {

         var Poll_insert_data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
         $('#poll_author').text(Poll_insert_data.data.publisherName);
         $('#owner_input_data').text("").append(Poll_insert_data.data.data);

         }
         );
         } else {
         alert('Please write something first.');
         }
    });
}
```

And that should work BUT, as Praveen Kumar has correctly pointed out, you should never change the id of an already rendered element. So you should instead use something like:

```
var update = false;

$('#textareaInsert').on('click', function () {
    if (update) {
        // do update logic
    } else {
        // do insert logic
        update = true;
    }
}
```

Which means no messing about with ids and duplicated handlers!

Comment: This worked, however, partially as now both graph_post_data() & graph_update_data()  are running together.

Comment: Did you change both click handlers to use delegation? Or just the update one?

Comment: Also, your code will always run both graph_post_data and graph_update_data as they are both called in document ready. What we are changing is which click handler is called

Comment: I just used delegation on update btn. When I applied on both it was not working. It did when I applied on either.

Comment: graph_post_data()  data runs an INSERT sql where as graph_update_data() runs UPDATE. That's why I need to change id to run different functions on single button. This is what I changed: $('#textareaInsert').on("click", function() { ... } and $(document).off('click', '#textareaInsert').on("click", '#textareaUpdate', function() { // }  . This is updating the desired row but also adding a similar and extra row. My Qtn is even after applying off() how's #textInsert btn working?

Comment: Answer updated, but note: The two functions you mention do not RUN anything! They add event handlers to the element. It is those handlers that run INSERT or UPDATE logic.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you. But I'm not being allowed to submit my final solution. Nevertheless, Steve Harris solution above has the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You don't attach an event to an id...you attach it to an element.

If you change properties and attributes of that element....it doesn't change the events that are bound to it.

So if you change the id...and use that selector to add a new event listener, you need to remove the old listener if you don't want it to be active any more

You can do something like:

```
$('#newID').off('click').on('click', function(){
   // do something
})
```

Comment: I did something like this-$('#textareaUpdate').off('click').on("click", function() { // } but it's still running graph_post_data() instead of graph_update_data()